# How do I get Google to reopen App suspended on google console?

Tags: android, flutter, google-developers-console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGHzS.png)
business app that is suspended, that suspended app recently when I uploaded the app it was rejected because some buttons didn't work, but I fixed them.  During the fix, I received a suspended email from Google, and it seemed like Google needed authorization to upload the app. I didn't understand why they asked for that. How do I get Google to reopen that app so I can update it?

Provide advance notice to the Google Play App Review team
The Google Play App Review team accepts advance notice about your upcoming app or store listing publishing event.

We only accept advance notice in the following scenario(s):

You have written documentation proving that you have permission to use a 3rd party's intellectual property in your app or store listing (e.g. Brand names and logos, graphic assets, audio, etc.).
You have written documentation proving that you have permission from a government or government agency to make apps on their behalf (e.g. apps that facilitate a government process such as voting or ID validation). This documentation must be submitted by the relevant government or government entity. Learn more
You have written documentation proving that you have permission from a recognized healthcare organization to develop and distribute an app in affiliation with them. Learn more
You have gambling or casino-style elements in your game, and need to provide your Korean Game Rating and Administrative Committee (GRAC) rating certificate to Google so your game can be distributed in Korea. Learn More
Your app uses an accessibility service and you need to provide an explanation documenting how the app uses the system capabilities that the service requests.
You are a validated non-profit charitable organization (for example, a validated 501(c)(3) charitable organization or the local equivalent). You should attach a copy of your organization’s IRS determination letter or other acceptable proof in your reply to this email. The provided information must indicate your status as a charitable organization.
You have written documentation obtained from a Law Enforcement Agency (e.g. police station) that needs to be submitted for review.
You have written documentation obtained from regulators that needs to be submitted for review.
Please Note: If you submit a request that's not covered by the above scenario(s), you may not receive a response. For other questions, contact our support team.

Answer (score 0):

Suspension is clearly based upon your app's "In App Experience". Detailed issues with screenshots you might have received on same mail from Google. Also go through each and every tabs on Play Console and check everything required by Google is already filled such Privacy policy, Data privacy & deletion,etc. Do check that and fix those as well and republish the app.

Comment: So now I need to rebuild a new version of the app and re-upload it from scratch instead of the suspended version, right?

Comment: No you do not have to create new app if that is your business related. Do check all the requirement on Play Console and update anything required on the Play Console. Fix the issue mentioned on the email from Google team and publish new version of your current app with updated version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Contact the Google Play Support Team. (Very unlikely that it'll get fixed at their end)
2. You will have to publish the app again with a different package name.